# React redux dispatch action to connect to mqtt

Tags: reactjs, redux, mqtt

I am building an react application to connect to and display data from a MQTT server.

I have implemented the basic connection code in `mqtt/actions.js` See below:

```
const client = mqtt.connect(options);

client.on('connect', function () {
  mqttConnectionState('MQTT_CONNECTED')

  client.subscribe(['btemp', 'otemp'], (err, granted) => {
    if (err) alert(err)
    console.log(`Subscribed to: otemp & btemp topics`)
  })
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  updateTemp({topic: topic, value: message.toString()})
});

const mqttConnectionState = (action, err = null) => {
  return {
    type: action,
    payload: err
  }
}
```

I am looking to on button press initiate the mqtt connection and then dispatch a connection success event.

However with the above code I am unsure exactly how this would work.

I could move the connect line `const client = mqtt.connect(options);` to a function and run that function on button click but then then the `client.on` functions will not be able to see the `client const`.

How is best to approach this?

I am using React.JS, Redux and the MQTT.JS libraries.

Update: Trying to dispatch and action when a message is received

Reducer:

```
const createClient = () => {
  const client = mqtt.connect(options);

  client.on('connect', function () {
    mqttConnectionState('MQTT_CONNECTED')

    client.subscribe(['btemp', 'otemp'], (err, granted) => {
      if (err) alert(err)
      console.log(`Subscribed to: otemp & btemp topics`)
    });
  });

  client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log('message received from mqtt')
    processMessage({topic, message})
  })

  return client;
}

case MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
      console.log('message received')
      messageReceived(payload)

      return state;
```

Actions:

```
export const processMessage = (data) => dispatch => {
  console.log('Processing Message')
  return {
    type: 'MESSAGE_RECEIVED',
    payload: data
  }
}
```

`message received from mqtt` log each time a message arrives, however `processMessage({topic, message})` never executes as `Processing Message` never logs to the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Actions are payloads of information that send data from your application to your store" ([docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions))

So you have to create the `client` in the Reducer (his function). Put it on the Redux `state` like this:

```
initialState = {
 client: null 
}
```

and you reducer.js file should look like this:

```
import {
  mqttConnectionState
} from './actions'
 

 
let initialState = {
  client: null ,
  err: null
}

const createClient = () => {
 const client = mqtt.connect(options);

 client.on('connect', function () {
   mqttConnectionState('MQTT_CONNECTED')

   client.subscribe(['btemp', 'otemp'], (err, granted) => {
     if (err) alert(err)
     console.log(`Subscribed to: otemp & btemp topics`)
   });
 });

 return client;
}

function app(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INIT_CONNECTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        client: createClient()
      })
    case 'MQTT_CONNECTED':
      return {
        ...state,
        err: action.payload
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and you actions.js:

```
...
const mqttConnectionInit = () => {
  return {
    type: 'INIT_CONNECTION'
  }
}

const mqttConnectionState = (err = null) => {
  return {
    type: 'MQTT_CONNECTED',
    payload: err
  }
}
...
```

this way you can dispatch the action mqttConnectionInit in the onclick button event.

Comment: Thanks Henrique, this works. How would I go about add the mqtt.on('message') functionality for this sort of flow? Should I dispatch an action once subscribed to topics that then listens for messages?

Comment: I think you can do it in the createClient method. And yes, you can dispatch an action in the "message" event, like wise you did in the "connect" event.

Comment: Ok, so i tried to solve this, I can receive messages (logs to the console on each time) I then make a call to a function in the actions which should distpatch a `message received action` however calling this method from the reducer never works. I.e. the method just doesn't execute, wont even console log when I receive a message.

I have updated my createClient() method above.

Comment: In 2022 or at least with mqtt 4.3.7, we cannot store mqtt object in redux's state. It is an non-serializable object.

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching Redux actions inside a reducer may clear your store. I mean, setting it's state to what you have under `initialState`. And require cycles are no-op.
Yesterday I did some changes in my code, because I've tried solution above and ended up with a warning "require cycles are allowed but can result in uninitialized values". I moved mqtt connection related code into the middleware.

```
import { DEVICE_TYPE, HOST, PASSWORD, PORT, USER_NAME } from '../utils/variables';
import { mqttConnectionInit, mqttConnectionState } from '../actions/devices';
import mqtt from 'mqtt/dist/mqtt';
import { SIGNED_IN } from '../constants/types';

const MqttMiddleware = store => next => action => {
  if (action.type == SIGNED_IN) {
    store.dispatch(mqttConnectionInit());
    const client = mqtt.connect(`ws://${HOST}:${PORT}`, { username: USER_NAME, password: PASSWORD });

    client.on('connect', function () {
      let license = store.getState().auth.license;
      store.dispatch(mqttConnectionState(client));
      client.subscribe(`/${USER_NAME}/${license}/+/${DEVICE_TYPE}/#`);
    });

    client.on('message', ((topic, payload) => {
      const device = JSON.parse(message(topic, payload.toString()));
      console.log(device);
    }));
  }

  next(action);
};

export function message(message, value) {
  const msg = message.split('/');
  return JSON.stringify({
    "id": msg[3],
    "user": msg[1],
    "license": msg[2],
    "type": msg[4],
    "name": msg[5],
    "value": value == "0" ? 0 : (value.match(/[A-Za-z]/) ? value : Number(value))
  });
}

export default MqttMiddleware;
```

You can do pretty much all you want with the store.

```
actions.js
```

```
import { INIT_CONNECTION, MQTT_CONNECTED } from '../constants/types'

export const mqttConnectionInit = () => {
  return {
    type: INIT_CONNECTION
  }
}

export const mqttConnectionState = (client, err = null) => {
  return {
    type: MQTT_CONNECTED,
    error: err,
    client: client,
  }
}
```

```
reducers.js
```

```
import { INIT_CONNECTION, MQTT_CONNECTED } from '../constants/types';

const mqttReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INIT_CONNECTION:
        return {
          ...state,
          client: null,
        };
      case MQTT_CONNECTED:
        return {
          ...state,
          err: action.error,
          client: action.client,
        };
      default:
        return state;
  }
}

const initialState = {
  client: null,
  err: null,
}

export default mqttReducer;
```